# How to display the Content type custom fields in twig template?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am very new to Drupal.

Can anyone tell me how to display the custom fields content type into twig template?

Thank you

I used below code with content and nodes.

{{ content.field_a }}

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to follow these steps :

**Step 1) Custom template for a content type**

Suppose, you have to create a new template for content type i.e. Article ( machine_name : article ). Just make a copy of node.html.twig and rename with node--article.html.twig

**Step 2) Call custom field**

In this template, you can display content of your field like {{ content.field_test_field }}

**Step 3) Clear Cache**

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create a full page template for an Article for example, you can create a file called : **page--node--article.html.twig**

Any custom content type would follow the pattern, for example if the content type is called Machine Product, the template would be: **page--node--machine-product.html.twig** (1 dash between spaces of the content type name.

For Drupal 8, this is my typical mapping for this filetype :

Blocks:
{{ page.REGIONNAME }}

Title: 
{{ node.title.value }}

Taxonomy Terms/Dropdown Selects in Create Content: 
{{ node.field_FIELDNAME.0.entity.label  }}

General Text Fields:
{{ node.field_FIELDNAME.value  }}

Images/Files:
{{ file_url(node.field_FIELDNAME.entity.fileuri')) }}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
{{ node.field_txt1.value }}
```